# How to detect window size in Next.js SSR using react hook?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-dates

I am building an app using Next.js and [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates).

I have two component **DateRangePicker** component and **DayPickerRangeController** component.

I want to render **DateRangePicker** when the window's width is bigger than size 1180px, if the size is smaller than this I want to render **DayPickerRangeController** instead.

Here is the code:

```
      windowSize > 1180 ?
           <DateRangePicker
             startDatePlaceholderText="Start"
             startDate={startDate}
             startDateId="startDate"
             onDatesChange={handleOnDateChange}
             endDate={endDate}
             endDateId="endDate"
             focusedInput={focus}
             transitionDuration={0}
             onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => {
               if (!focusedInput) {
                 setFocus("startDate")
               } else {
                 setFocus(focusedInput)
                }
               }}
                /> :
             <DayPickerRangeController
               isOutsideRange={day => isInclusivelyBeforeDay(day, moment().add(-1, 'days'))}
               startDate={startDate}
               onDatesChange={handleOnDateChange}
               endDate={endDate}
               focusedInput={focus}
               onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => {
               if (!focusedInput) {
                 setFocus("startDate")
                 } else {
                  setFocus(focusedInput)
                 }
               }}
              /> 
          }
```

I normally use react hook with window object to detect window screen width like [this](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/)

But I found that this way is not available when ssr because ssr rendering does not have window object.

Is there an alternative way I can get window size safely regardless of ssr?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can avoid calling your detection function in ssr by adding this code:

```
// make sure your function is being called in client side only
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // detect window screen width function
}
```

full example from your link:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Usage
function App() {
  const size = useWindowSize();

  return (
    <div>
      {size.width}px / {size.height}px
    </div>
  );
}

// Hook
function useWindowSize() {
  // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
  // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // only execute all the code below in client side
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      // Set window width/height to state
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }
    
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
     
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();
    
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
  return windowSize;
}
```

NB: Updated as Sergey Dubovik comment, we dont need to validate windows since useEffect run in client side

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, useEffect only runs on client, so if (typeof window !== 'undefined') condition should not be needed

Comment: If you're writing this in Typescript you might get the TS1251: Function declarations are not allowed inside blocks in strict mode when targeting 'ES3' or 'ES5'. 

If so, just move the handleResize() function outside the if statement

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this solutions doesn't work if need the window size on initial page load because width and height are set to undefined

Comment: I found that it is necessary to call the `setWindowSize` directly in `useEffect`, and not just pass it in as an argument to `window.addEventListener`. The event listener on "resize" was not sufficient to populate the window dimensions in the initial load of the page.

Answer (score 38):

While [Darryl RN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6130753/darryl-rn) has provided an absolutely correct answer. I'd like to make a small remark: You don't really need to check for the existence of the `window` object inside `useEffect` because `useEffect` only runs client-side and never server-side, and the `window` object is always available on the client-side.

Comment: I kept seeing this comment about useEffect not running server-side. yet it looked like thats what was happening. Then i noticed that the code i'd used was passing a function into the initial state useState<T>(() => { dosomethingWithWindow}). which was getting called by serverside renderer. So thanks for the reminder that this was the case.

Comment: This isn't true because nextjs will lint the code and fail to compile with an error about the variable not existing if the undefined case isn't protected against

Comment: If this answer didn't work for you, here's another option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66696801/332578

Answer (score 7):

```
useEffect(()=> {
   window.addEventListener('resize', ()=> {
       console.log(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth)
   })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I was getting errors, but this worked for me.
Only for width:

```
const useWidth = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth)
  useEffect(() => {
      handleResize()
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
  return width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution i'm using: a small npm package found here [use-window-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rooks/use-window-size)

once installed and imported, all you need to do is use it like this:

```
const { innerWidth, innerHeight, outerHeight, outerWidth } = useWindowSize();

return (
    <div>Window width: {innerWidth}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of 'use client' for this page and just treat it as a client side component, which it will be.

[Client side components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components)

Then you can avoid all the hacks because of SSR otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I like Darryl RN's solution. If you are facing an issue that `size.width` is ***undefined*** initially when the page loads, just simply initialise the state with `window.innerWidth`

```
const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to my answer. Since the solutions above will throw an error and say that the size is not defined or equal to 0, depending on what useState is initialized with at the beginning. And this happens because when the page has already been rendered by the server and any override of components occurs, the hook will show the value undefined. To the extent that this is what is specified in useState. The solution is simple and elegant: just call the function in useEffect. The decision is not mine.

```
type WindowSize = {
  width: number | undefined;
  height: number | undefined;
};

const useWindowSize = (): WindowSize => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState<WindowSize>({
      width: undefined,
      height: undefined,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize(): void {
      setSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return (): void => window.removeEventListener("resize", 
  handleResize);
  }, []);

  return size;
};
```