# How to set window resize event listener value to React State?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This issue is very simple but I probably overlook very little point. Window screen size is listening by `PostLayout` component. When window width is less than 768px, I expect that `isDesktopSize` is false. I tried everything like using arrow function in `setIsDesktopSize`, using text inside of true or false for state value, using callback method etc... but it's not working.

`PostLayout` shared below:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect, useCallback} from 'react'
import LeftSideNavbar from './LeftSideNavbar'
import TopNavbar from './TopNavbar'

export default function PostLayout({children}) {
    const [isDesktopSize, setIsDesktopSize] = useState(true)

    let autoResize = () => {
        console.log("Desktop: " + isDesktopSize);
        console.log(window.innerWidth);
        if(window.innerWidth < 768 ){
            setIsDesktopSize(false)
        }else{
            setIsDesktopSize(true)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', autoResize)
        autoResize();  
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <TopNavbar isDesktopSize={isDesktopSize}/>
            <main>
                <LeftSideNavbar/>
                {children}
            </main>
        </>  
    )
}
```

console log is shared below:

```
Desktop: true
627
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be extracted into a custom hook. There's a few things you'd want to address:

1. Right now you default the state to `true`, but when the component loads, that may not be correct. This is probably why you see an incorrect console log on the first execution of the effect. Calculating the initial state to be accurate could save you some jank/double rendering.
2. You aren't disconnecting the resize listener when the component unmounts, which could result in an error attempting to set state on the component after it has unmounted.

Here's an example of a custom hook that addresses those:

```js
function testIsDesktop() {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return true;
    }
    return window.innerWidth >= 768;
}

function useIsDesktopSize() {
    // Initialize the desktop size to an accurate value on initial state set
    const [isDesktopSize, setIsDesktopSize] = useState(testIsDesktop);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        function autoResize() {
            setIsDesktopSize(testIsDesktop());
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', autoResize);

        // This is likely unnecessary, as the initial state should capture
        // the size, however if a resize occurs between initial state set by
        // React and before the event listener is attached, this
        // will just make sure it captures that.
        autoResize();

        // Return a function to disconnect the event listener
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', autoResize);
    }, [])

    return isDesktopSize;
}
```

Then to use this, your other component would look like this (assuming your custom hook is just in this same file -- though it may be useful to extract it to a separate file and import it):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import LeftSideNavbar from './LeftSideNavbar'
import TopNavbar from './TopNavbar'

export default function PostLayout({children}) {
    const isDesktopSize = useIsDesktopSize();

    return (
        <>
            <TopNavbar isDesktopSize={isDesktopSize}/>
            <main>
                <LeftSideNavbar/>
                {children}
            </main>
        </>  
    )
}
```

EDIT: I modified this slightly so it should theoretically work with a server-side renderer, which will assume a desktop size.

Comment: thank you for response Marc Baumbach. When I try your suggestion, i catch continuously 'window is not defined' error. I research the this error. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406435/how-to-detect-window-size-in-next-js-ssr-using-react-hook#63408216) can be  solution but not working me. Actually GoonGamja's issue is same with me. Finally, i can not passed this compile error.

Comment: @swim Is this code also running on a server-side renderer? This code assumes it's only ever being run on the browser. `window` is always available in a browser.

Comment: I modified the code to check for whether `window` is defined. If not, it basically doesn't run and assumes that it is a desktop size, though there's probably no definitively correct solution for that.

Comment: **Desktop size value is setting currectly now :)** This aim of question is adding responsive attribute using isDesktopSize value. When "isDesktopSize" value is false, some elements in my topnavbar component should be disappaer.  I catch a warning like " className did not match . Server: TopNavbar d-flex", Client: "TopNavbar d-none". So, application take decision from server side. these issues like window, unmatching class attributes due to ssr application and i can migrate plain react project or client side project.

Comment: I learned that **dynamic import without ssr**. This import style is solution for my unmacthing class attribute. Initial value of class attributes is setting correctly because anymore TopNavbar component is importing client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are setting isDesktopSizze to 'mobile', which is === true

```html
const [isDesktopSize, setIsDesktopSize] = useState(true)

let autoResize = () => {
        console.log("Desktop: " + isDesktopSize);
        console.log(window.innerWidth);
        if(window.innerWidth < 768 ){
            setIsDesktopSize(true)
        }else{
            setIsDesktopSize(false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you quick response but i update my question and change these lines. you can remove answer but thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find such a package on npm and I thought it would be nice to create one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-device-detect. I think it will help someone :)