# Get scrollbar position with NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using NextJs to take advantage of Server Side Rendering. And also I have a navbar in my application that should change styles with scroll position. How can I check whether the window has been scrolled more than 100px, on my NextJs application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use a `useEffect` hook like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScrollY(window.scrollY);
    };

    // just trigger this so that the initial state 
    // is updated as soon as the component is mounted
    // related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63408216
    handleScroll();

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 4000 }}> {/* just added to make scrollbar available */}
      <div style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0 }}>
        {scrollY > 100
          ? "Scrolled more than 100px"
          : "Still somewhere near the top!"}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-drake-1xe0g

This code can be further optimized by debouncing the scroll handler. And optionally, setting the state only if it is not changed (not sure if newer versions of React handle this itself).

Your question was directly related to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403018/11613622

For debouncing/throttling you can refer this: [How to use throttle or debounce with React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54666401/11613622)

Also if you don't want to use the provided solutions in that thread simply wrap the `handleScroll` with `_.debounce` and then feed it to the event handler.

Comment: I'm using ServerSide rendering here and I suspect that's why I"m not seeing the output. Could you try adding SSR to the page and see if this work please? It didn't work for me

Comment: @SachinTitus It is working on SSR also, I have updated the sandbox to export `getServerSideProps` which will make Next.js server render that page.

Comment: Do you expect this code snippet ot work on any of the higher order components and other components as well? I have a Layout Component which is an HOC i use inside the page

Comment: if I wrap the page content with Layout hoc, it doesn't seem to work. but if there's no HOC around the code inside return statement, it works

Comment: @SachinTitus Technically wrapping your component in some HOC should not effect this functionality. Can you show the relevant code that your Layout HOC is putting? Also, I didn't quite understand what you meant by _"other components"_. The state will be accessible inside whatever component you define it.

Comment: I'll create a code sandbox and share it with you. Thank you for helping mind

Comment: Got the solution. It's the overflow-x:hidden in my code which causes the issue. Thanks for the help