# Window is not defined with custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am facing a problem I can't seem to solve.

I have a custom hook that sets the height and width of the window. But since nextjs is SSR I get the error that window is not defined.

My problem lies in putting the hook in a if statement or useeffect hook.

Current code (useWindowDimensions.tsx):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function getWindowDimensions() {
    const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window
    return {
        width,
        height,
    }
}

export default function useWindowDimensions() {
    const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions())

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions())
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
        // code here
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }, [])

    return windowDimensions
}
```

Current code:

```
const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions()

const dimensions = () => {
        if (width > 1900) return width * 0.4
        if (width > 1000) return width * 0.3
        if (width > 800) return width * 0.2
        if (width < 800) return width * 0.1
    }
```

I can't put getWindowDimensions() in an useEffect because the rules of hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
    function getWindowDimensions() {
        const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window
        return {
            width,
            height,
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect window size in Next.js SSR using react hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406435/how-to-detect-window-size-in-next-js-ssr-using-react-hook)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting the error because in Next.js your code is first server side rendered, and on server there are no browser globals like `window`, `document`, etc. To fix it, you can do this:

```
export default function useWindowDimensions() {
    const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState({width: 0, height: 0}) // <-- don't invoke here

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions())
        }

        handleResize() // <-- invoke this on component mount
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
        
        return () => { window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize) }
    }, [])

    return windowDimensions
}
```

It will work because `useEffect` is guaranteed to run on client side only.

Also refer: [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041) and [How to detect window size in Next.js SSR using react hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406435) if you wish to create a hook that handles this for you.

Answer (score 4):

Check if `window` is defined or not:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // You now have access to `window`
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app#safely-accessing-web-apis